# Probability of males majoring in zoology

Tags: probability

At a certain university, **28%** of students major in zoology. Of all the students majoring in zoology, **68%** are males. It is also known that **56%** of all students at the university are male. Let **Z** represent the event that a randomly chosen student is majoring in zoology. Let **M** represent the event that a randomly chosen student is male.
What proportion of males at the university are majoring in zoology?

Previously solved for **P(M∩Z)=0.1904** and this is correct.
I've tried **P(Z|M) = P(M∩Z) / P(Z)**, and get the answer **0.68** which is the probability that a student majoring in zoology is a male. The correct answer is **0.34**, which is exactly half, but I am not sure how to get this answer.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The equation $P(Z\vert M) = P(M\cap Z) / P(Z)$ is equivalent to $P(Z)P(Z\vert M) = P(M\cap Z)$, which is not correct. http://stattrek.com/probability/probability-rules.aspx

Comment: Thank you, I took a look at the site and found where I went wrong.

Comment: Great! Glad you found the solution!

Answer (score 2):

Let it be that there are $10000$ students in total.

Then $2800$ of them major in zoology and $68\times28=1904$ of these are male.

Also it is known that $5600$ of all students are male.

So the proportion of males majoring in zoology is: $$\frac{1904}{5600}$$

Comment: Thank you very much for the further explanation.

Comment: You are welcome. Nice to see that you found it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to mathmandan I found my error and got the right answer.

**P(Z|M) = P(M∩Z) / P(M) = 0.1904/0.56 = 0.34**

Should have been divided by **P(M)**, not **P(Z)**.